# resetStyle in geoJSON pointToLayer circleMarkers

Tags: leaflet

I am creating a geoJSON layer, with pointToLayer returning circleMarkers. In that layer's oneachfeature, I am triggering a style change on hover, and this works fine. However, I cannot reset the style on mouseout. It all works with lines and polygons, but not with points created as circleMarkers via pointToLayers.

How can I reset the style of such circleMarkers on mouseout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method is to create your own reset function using setStyle to be run on mouseout. For example:

```
function resetHighlight(e) {
    var layer = e.target;
    layer.setStyle(StyleDefault);
}
```

(where StyleDefault is your default circleMarker style, defined elsewhere)

Here is an [example fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/nathansnider/xyeppq5j/) using some synthetic data.

Comment: Just what I've ended up doing. I still don't quote understand why resetStyle is not available, but your answer is perfect. Thanks.

Comment: To reset everything, looks like you can use geoJsonLayer.setStyle({...}) and just give it the same options when the layer was first created